# updating lucene index

Tags: lucene

What is the best way to update an existing Lucene index. I dont't just have to add/delete documents from it, rather update the existing documents.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will have to open the index without overwriting thus:

```
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter("MyIndexPath",analyzer, false);
```

The false flag at the end tells it to open in append mode.

The writer has an UpdateDocument method

```
writer.UpdateDocument(new Term("IDField",id), doc);
```

the id field should be some unique document identifier such as filename or file number etc.

Comment: I thought that this was not possible. http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#How_do_I_update_a_document_or_a_set_of_documents_that_are_already_indexed.3F

Comment: @Neelesh given the ambiguity in the question tags, and the capitalization of `UpdateDocument`, I suspect that this answer is for lucene.net.

Comment: A document can be updated with updateDocument (which just deletes and then adds the entire document). http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html